# Characterize a set, consisting of multiples of a rational number r mod (2π)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm trying to characterize a set, consisting of multiples of a rational number r modulo $2 \pi$, i.e.:

$M = \{(rn)mod(2\pi)$ $ $ $  |$ $ $ $  n\in \mathbb N \}$, $ $ $r \in \mathbb Q$

The reason I am interested in it, is that I am trying to quantify the magnitude of sums like: $$S(r)= \sum_{k=1}^{N} exp(2 \pi kr)$$

where N is pretty large. Once I'm able to define a finite set $M$, I might be able to approximate a magnitude for $S$. So how would I best go about finding out the cardinality of M?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $M$ is dense in $[0,2\pi]$ since $r$ is rational. Otherwise suppose it has a smallest element $a$, you have $a= rn +2p\pi$, $r(n+l)=2q_l\pi+m_la$, $n,p,q_l,m_l,l$ are integers and $m_la\in [0,2\pi]$. this implies $m_la=m_lnr+2pm_l\pi=r(n+l)-2q_l\pi$. You deduce that

$(2pm_l+2q_l)\pi=r(n+l-m_ln)$. This implies that $n+l=m_ln$ and $n(m_l-1)=l$, thus $n$ divides every integer, we deduce that $|n|=1$, remark that there exists $B>0$ such that $m_l<B$ since $m_la\in [0,2\pi]$. This implies that $|n(1-m_l)|=|l|$ is bounded for every integer $l$. Contradicition.

So $inf M=0$, this implies that $M$ is infinite (what you need) but it implies also that $M$ is dense, since for every $m\in M, l\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $lm<2\pi, lm\in M$.

Comment: Which means that $M$ is countably infinite.

Comment: Thank you Tsemo Aristide. Could you elaborate a little ?  Would i be able to determine some kind of distribution for the numbers, depending on r?